# How can I fix my CSS Positioning

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am trying to get my footer to be at bottom of page, header at top of page and section in the middle of page. But all I get is the red footer displayed on top of page. The background wrapper should be gray but that doesn't work either. Please help. Thank you.

Here is the css:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
section {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

below is the body of the html:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <header>

        </header>
        <section>

        </section>
        <footer>

        </footer>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to html/body:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use `position: absolute;`. It tends to mess up all of your spacing when used in parent elements like that.  The `section` section will be placed right over the `header` section because it hasn't been positioned at all.

Try just giving the `section` a  min height and removing the `position` attributes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments I fixed it with the above html/body instructions. All the comments make sense thank yoy.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Replace the CSS definition for `<body>`:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make this in following class in your code :

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top:20px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5k7KX/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position absolute from the header, footer and section. I think it might be it.